# Как обратиться к i структурному элементу массива?

Tags: массивы, структуры

Как обратиться к i структурному элементу массива? Вот так выдаёт ошибку: требуется имя члена или выражение должно иметь тип указателя

```
trash[i]->direction_vert
```

, где `trash` массив структур.

Answer (score 1):

`trash` массив структур:

```
trash[i].direction_vert
```

Comment: нет, он у меня в функцию передаётся по ссылке

Comment: @MrFilonxik Не "нет", а "да".

Comment: я имею ввиду, что нужно через -> т.к он у меня передаётся по ссылке в функцию. Я попробовал, как вы написали выше, но ошибка осталась: выражение должен иметь тип указателя.

Comment: @MrFilonxik Вы понимаете, что мне сквозь монитор плохо виден Ваш код?

Comment: Существует структура: typedef struct {
 int coord;
 int row, col;
 char direction_vert;
 char direction_hor;
 int speed;
 char parameters[4];
} trash_t; Массив: trash_t trash[51];  Я хочу к нему обратиться в функции: void make_trash_move(gamestate_t *gms, trash_t trash[]) { if ((trash[i]->row == 1 || trash[i]->row == SIZE_ROW) }

Comment: @MrFilonxik `trash[i].row`. Откуда взялось `i`?

Comment: из цикла for (i = 0; i < gms->trash_num; i++)

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, почему если меняю на trash[i].direction_vert, вместо trash[i]->direction_vert, то ошибка пропадает, хотя выражение находится в функции и trash передаётся по ссылке?